# Incoming messages send again by openerp

Tags: odoo

When someone sends an email message, it can view on openerp inbox but the outgoing email sends again thru the configuration email address I set up.. why is it so?

I'm using Openerp v7.0.. I used the Outgoing Mail Server in the Settings > Technical > Email > Outgoing Mail Servers.

When someone sends an email and openerp retrieved it, it sends again and again an email but by using the email address I configure.

[image: email message]

Answer (score 5):

Your question is not quite clear<sup>[1]</sup>, but this sounds like the default and correct behavior. When an OpenERP user receives an external email message, they will by default receive a copy of the email at their own email address (configured in their user preferences).

Let's say someone replies to a CRM Lead assigned to me (by sending an email to `info@mycompany.com`, which is imported via the `fetchmail` module into my OpenERP server): I want to receive a copy of this message in my real inbox at `myname@mycompany.com`).

In OpenERP 7.0 this behavior can be controlled in the *"Email Preferences"* of the user profiles: you can choose to receive email notification about new comments and new external emails, or about new external emails only, or no notification whatsoever.

---

<sup>[1]</sup>: The following information would help: the version of OpenERP you're using, how the emails are being fed to OpenERP (`fetchmail` module, mail gateway script, something else...), what email addresses are being fed to OpenERP, what email is configured on the user profiles, etc.