# Messaging Recipients Clarification

Tags: odoo

Why does when my other email sends a message to my email that is connected to openerp and been replied to, the recipient showing is only the users name and not the sender's email address?

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

In User Context menu feeds Email notification is on for all Feeds By Email.

- User Preferences :

  - Email Preferences

    - Receive Feeds by Email

and OpenERP their is Alias for user so you get user name in reply.

Here's More nice explanation by Odony: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14315495/incoming-messages-send-again-by-openerp)